# webkit animation rotate not working in Nexus Mobile

Tags: css, ionic-framework, core-animation, css-transitions, css-animations

I am creating a double ring radar animation in an Ionic hybrid application. 
It is working fine in browser but it is not working in the Nexus mobile but works fine in other mobile.

Sample : [Code pen example](http://codepen.io/fixcl/pen/lvCFr)

If i remove the following two lines in the before after of Holo element then it displays otherwise it needs a shake or rotate to initiate the animation.

```
-webkit-animation: rotarIz 2s -0.5s linear infinite;
          animation: rotarIz 2s -0.5s linear infinite;
```

Comment: is iyt happening for all nexus devices or for a particular nexus device?

Comment: It happens Nexus 5S with latest Marshmellow and i dont know about other Nexus models

Answer (score 0):

I coudn't test in Nexus mobile but can you change the infinite parameter for an int value and test it again?

```
-webkit-animation: rotarIz 2s -0.5s linear 10;
animation: rotarIz 2s -0.5s linear 10;
```